# Multiword define through a poorly structured makefile system

Tags: c, makefile, c-preprocessor

I'm making a small change to a legacy project, and I need to pass a define that has more than one word to the command line, like so:

```
CFLAGS += -DXXX="A B"
```

Unfortunately, with the way this project was structured, my makefile fragment doesn't have access to the `CFLAGS` variable, or any other global for that matter. I only have something like `CUSTOM_DEFINES` exposed, which gets appended to `CFLAGS` later.

From what I've understood, the makefiles eventually do an equivalent of

```
CFLAGS += $(addprefix -D,$(CUSTOM_DEFINES))
```

which results in this command line option: `-DXXX="A -DB"`, the equivalent of `#define XXX A -DB` instead of `#define XXX A B`.

Is there some magic sequence I can add to `CUSTOM_DEFINES` to end up with the correct result?

---

Avoiding the XY problem, here's some context:

I'm trying to force a fragile old system to swallow a broken system header (which I also can't change). The header in one place doesn't define the return type:

```
/*implicit int */ SomeLegacyFunction(int a, int b) { return a + b; }
```

The compiler will not accept this (and I can't really change the compiler params). Since `SomeLegacyFunction` is never used, I want to just do something like:

```
#define SomeLegacyFunction int SomeLegacyFunction
```

and get it compiling. Any suggestions how to do this another way are just as welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
CUSTOM_DEFINES=Func="int/**/Func"
```

or

```
CUSTOM_DEFINES=Func="int(Func)"
```

may be worth trying. You almost never really need whitespace in C.

Comment: Thanks! `CUSTOM_DEFINES=Func="int/* */Func"` did the trick. The space in the comment was necessary, so that `-D` ends up in a  comment.

Comment: @mtijanic: I think the second suggestion, with parentheses, would be better, since putting comments in a command-line preprocessor define is unspecified behaviour (comments should be removed before preprocessor directives are interpreted). But I suppose whatever works, works, in this case :)

Comment: @rici I agree, but unfortunately, that one doesn't work. Neither does `(int)func`. And indeed, I don't think this would work on GCC, but this is MSVC.

Comment: @mtijanic: `(int)func` is invalid syntax, but `int(func)` should work even with MSVC, since it's a standard way of avoiding function-like macro expansion. Perhaps it's a problem with the parentheses in the command-line? Certainly, MSVC's preprocessor is, um, idiosyncratic.